# Comparing pointer with char end of string

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I know that when comparing a char pointer with some char value you need to prefix the pointer with `*`, but I have found in some code a comparison like:

```
char* c;
// ... 
while (*c != ']' && *c != '\0') // search for some character 
{
    c++;
}
if (c == '\0')
{
    return -1; // error
}
```

So, my question is: is this a bug or a special case? Shouldn't there be `if (*c == '\0')` there?

Comment: bad way for checking NULL.

Comment: Yes, dereferencing would seem like a logical thing to do in this case, so it's most likely a bug.

Comment: It's a bug. That effectively checks `c` for NULL, which should have been done in `// ...` in the first place. The author probably meant `if (*c == '\0')` as a check to see if the loop landed on the terminator vs a `']'`.

Comment: A modern compiler will in fact eliminate the whole second condition. It deduces that `c` is not a null pointer from the facts that the code above did `*c` and from knowing that the null pointer isn't reachable by doing `c++`. Therefore the test simplifies to `if(false)` and can be removed outright.

Comment: @MSalters so you are saying that if the `c` pointer ends with `\0` and the while loop ends because of the end of the pointer (that is `\0` character) the `if` will not return -1 because there was no `]`?

Comment: @sop: No, my statement was a lot stronger: I said that the whole if-statment, including `return -1` will be entire removed by an optimizing  compiler.

Comment: So, you are saying that if there is  no `]` in the string then the program will crash somewhere because the `if` was removed??

Comment: @sop: Probably, yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Null Pointers**

The integer constant literal 0 has different meanings depending upon the context in which it's used. In all cases, it is still an integer constant with the value 0, it is just described in different ways.

If a pointer is being compared to the constant literal 0, then this is a check to see if the pointer is a null pointer. This 0 is then referred to as a null pointer constant. The C standard defines that 0 cast to the type void * is both a null pointer and a null pointer constant.

Additionally, to help readability, the macro NULL is provided in the header file `stddef.h`.

Therefore, here are some valid ways to check for a null pointer:

`if (pointer == NULL)`

`NULL` is defined to compare equal to a null pointer. It is implementation defined what the actual definition of NULL is, as long as it is a valid null pointer constant.

`if (pointer == 0)`

0 is another representation of the null pointer constant.

**Null Characters**

`'\0'` is defined to be a null character - that is a character with all bits set to zero. This has nothing to do with pointers. However you may see something similar to this code:

`if (!*string_pointer)`

checks if the string pointer is pointing at a null character

`if (*string_pointer)`

checks if the string pointer is pointing at a non-null character.

> So, my question is: is this a bug or a special case? Shouldn't there be if (*c == '\0') there?

The statement in your code `if (c == '\0')` checks if the pointer itself equals 0. That is, it checks for c being a Null pointer.
But I think it is a bug, because the statement to check if c is a `NULL` pointer is after accessing the value stored at c. I think the program is about to locate a character `]`. If it found the character `]` before the null character, then it doesn't return -1.
So, the corrected statement should be-

```
if (*c == '\0')
{
    return -1; // It didn't found the '[' character!
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You are right.

```
c == '\0'
```

checks if the pointer itself equals 0, not the character where the pointer points to.